# Getting data from two columns in Excel, adding new rows automatically

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Is it possible to get data from two columns (using comma as a delimiter) and have it insert new rows for each comma?  I'm trying to fix data entered in a form, where multiple first names and multiple emails were entered in one row; EG col A has "John, Annie, Frantubulous" and Col B [email] contains "john@dumb.com, Annie@aol.com, frantan69@gmail.com" all in one row. I want to separate each entry (marked by commas) into its own line and not manually have to comb each of the entries and add new rows.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do this. What have you tried? You could start with the Data --> Data to Columns, using comma delimiters.

Comment: I thought about Text to Column but it says it'll only operate on one column, and then it ends up as columns not rows.  I essentially just want to add a row for each delimiter (comma) and the proceeding text in the new row.